# How to view Lightning app/pages on new Lightning Experience app?

Tags: lightning-apps

I was fiddling out with new Lightning experience. I created a Lightning page using the App builder and activated it. Its showing me in the mobile app but on lightning experience on desktop I am unable to view them. Is there something am missing?

Comment: Are you looking to attach to left navigation?

Comment: if possible yes... attaching anywhere would do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is currently not possible to create new standalone pages for the Lightning Experience using the Lightning App Builder. There is a self service pilot available to Developer Edition orgs to customize the record detail pages using the App Builder, see http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lex_edit_record_home_with_lab.htm

The other option is to expose the Lightning Component directly (without using the App Builder) in the App Launcher by following the steps outlined by Mohith Shrivastava.

Comment: Precisely that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

> You will have to implement the interface "force:appHostable" for your component to appear in the lightning new experience

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
```

> Follow these steps to include your components in Lightning Experience and make them available to users in your organization.

**Create a custom tab for this component.**

1. From Setup, enter Tabs in the Quick Find box, then select Tabs.
   Click New in the Lightning Component Tabs related list.
2. Select the Lightning component that you want to make available to
       users.
3. Enter a label to display on the tab.
4. Select the tab style and click Next.
5. When prompted to add the tab to profiles, accept the default and
           click Save.

**Assign your Lightning components to a custom app.**

2. Create a custom app and name it Lightning.
3. Select the Lightning app you created and then click Edit.
4. In the Custom App Edit page, select the components you want to
       include, click Add, and then Save.

> Check your output by navigating to the App Launcher in Lightning Experience. Your custom app should appear in theApp Launcher. Click the custom app to see the components you added.
>
> **As of winter 16 there is no ability for adding to left navigation but safe harbor this will come soon in next release(BIG SAFE HARBOUR)**

Comment: i did all, even added flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes for component to make it available for app builer. and thats how i created an app.. but still i cannot see it in new lightning experience. i could see the lightning component tab ,but not the lightning app tab or so

Comment: You can make your components (.cmp resources) available in Lightning Experience and Salesforce1, but not apps (.app resources).

Comment: I guess the user wants in lightning experience and this looks straight to me

Comment: The question is about Lightning Pages created in the Lightning App Builder, this answer is about Lighting Components (.cmp) and Lightning Apps (.app). They are not the same.

Comment: @Kristian I see and it makes sense now .Thanks for heads up .I guess only way will be to create components similar to those pages for desktop views .